# date_i18n() issue

Tags: theme-development, multisite, multi-language

I'm trying to use date_i18n() to display a localised date in my theme.

```
<?php echo date_i18n( 'F j, Y',  strtotime( get_the_time( "Y-m-d" ) ) ); ?>
```

However, this always returns the English version of the month, rather than the French version. I'm using wordpress as a network. My primary site has the default WPLANG (so english), and I'm setting the second site to french by setting the WPLANG to fr_FR in site-settings.

Other translations on the page are working fine, so wordpress is aware that the language is different.

I downloaded the necessary .mo and .po files for French, but it doesn't have months in there, so I assume there's somewhere else these are set/used.

Any help would be appreciated as I've been stumped by this for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`date_i18n()`](http://queryposts.com/function/date_i18n/) gets month from `WP_Locale->get_month()`. Which in turn fills months using baseline translation function `__()`, nothing fancy.

Bottom line is — months *should* be translated in po/mo files, you just got incomplete translation.

Comment: FYI translations can be found inside localized WP download archives - [click here for all links](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/#all).